# How to invoke the API in a DLL file by JAVA on linux platform?

Tags: java, linux, dll

everyone! I have faced a problem, hope you can help me. 
We have developed a project on linux platform by JAVA, and a DLL file provides some useful API which can improve the speed of development. I want to use the API in the project. How to embed the DLL file into the project? Anyone could provide a solution? Thank you very much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows DLL on Linux System](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569591/windows-dll-on-linux-system)

Answer (score 2):

DLL's are Windows only shared libraries.
You will have to port the DLL to Linux before you can use it

Comment: +1, but I'd be curious to know if you could somehow incorporate wine to load/interpret the dlls. I'd assume that this isn't out of the box from wine and you'd most likely need to refactor the project source (at which point just re-writing the functionality in native code would most likely be easier)...